# Delete first X rows of MySQL table once the number of rows is greater than N

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have an insert-only table in MySQL named word. Once the number of rows exceeds 1000000, I would like to delete the first 100000 rows of the table.

I am using mysqldb in python, so I have a global variable:

```
wordcount = cursor.execute("select * from word")
```

will return the number of rows in the table in the python environment. I then increment the wordcount by 1 everytime I insert a new row. Then I check if the number of rows are greater than 1000000, if it is, I want to delete the first 100000 rows:

```
if wordcount > 1000000:
    cursor.execute("delete from word limit 100000")
```

I got this idea from this thread: 
[Delete first X lines of a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12779978/mysql-delete-first-x-lines-of-a-database)

However, this SQL ends of deleting my ENTIRE table, what am I missing here?

Thank you.

Comment: You are shure that `wordcount = cursor.execute("select * from word")` returns the number of records ?

Comment: In the python environment yes, in MySQL no. For example wordcount = cursor.execute("select count(*) from word") would return 1 in python, because it is  1 line. Whereas my SQL would return in the number of lines (in the python environment) which is the count

Comment: Did you read the `cursor` [doc](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#cursor-objects) ?

Comment: yes. I am mostly wonder if my why my sql is deleting the whole table instead of just the first 100000 rows

Comment: Find here example for fetching the row count: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511679/python-number-of-rows-affected-by-cursor-executeselect

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's the right way of getting the number of rows. You need to change your statement to have a `count(*)` and then use MySQLs cursor.fetchone() to get a tuple of the results, where the first position (kinda like `wordcount = cursor.fetchone()[0]`) will have the correct row count.

Your delete statement looks right, maybe you have explicit transactions? in which case you'd have to call `commit()` on your db object after the delete.

Answer (score 0):

If your table "word" have ID field (key auto_increment field) you may write some stored procedure of deleting first 100000-rows. The key part of stored procedure is:

```
drop temporary table if exists tt_ids;
create temporary table tt_ids (id int not null);

insert into tt_ids -- taking first 100000 rows
select id from word
order by ID
limit 100000;

delete w
from word w
join tt_ids ids on w.ID = ids.ID;

drop temporary table if exists tt_ids;
```

Also you may build some indexes on tt_ids on ID-field for a speed-UP your query.