# Removing same entries in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a beginner in MySQL. Here I had just created a table

```
CREATE TABLE Student (
    Rollno int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Gpa float,
);
```

Once after creating the table I had added the values with the help of the below query

```
USE persons;
INSERT INTO student
VALUES
 (1, 'Aa', 'A', 8.5),
 (2, 'Bb', 'B', 8.6),
 (3, 'Cc', 'C', 8.7),
 (4, 'Dd', 'D', 8.4);
```

I had just run the above query twice which resulted in having two entries as shown below
[image: Resultant Database]

So I just wanted to remove the duplicate entries and the resultant database should resemble as
[image: Required Database]

Though I searched and tried I don't possess any unique values like `id` mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5016434/13855094).

And again I tried with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18390654/13855094) the code is shown below

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        Rollno,
        LastName,
        FirstName,
        Gpa,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY
                Rollno
            ORDER BY
                Rollno
        )RN
     FROM
        persons.student
)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE RN > 1;
```

but the above throws error stating

> Error Code:1288. The target table cte of the DELETE is not updatable

So I just wanted an optimal solution to have single entries in the table.

Comment: Use LIMIT for delete statement. See answer at: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12779978/delete-first-x-lines-of-a-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12779978/delete-first-x-lines-of-a-database)

Comment: Drop and re-create the table with rollno assigned as the primary key. Then re-do the inserts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution I tested using your data. Thank you for providing a case that was complete and easy to test!

```
mysql> alter table student add column id int auto_increment primary key first;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from student;
+----+--------+----------+-----------+------+
| id | Rollno | LastName | FirstName | Gpa  |
+----+--------+----------+-----------+------+
|  1 |      1 | Aa       | A         |  8.5 |
|  2 |      2 | Bb       | B         |  8.6 |
|  3 |      3 | Cc       | C         |  8.7 |
|  4 |      4 | Dd       | D         |  8.4 |
|  5 |      1 | Aa       | A         |  8.5 |
|  6 |      2 | Bb       | B         |  8.6 |
|  7 |      3 | Cc       | C         |  8.7 |
|  8 |      4 | Dd       | D         |  8.4 |
+----+--------+----------+-----------+------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> delete s1 from student as s1 join student as s2 on s1.rollno=s2.rollno and s1.id > s2.id;
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> select * from student;
+----+--------+----------+-----------+------+
| id | Rollno | LastName | FirstName | Gpa  |
+----+--------+----------+-----------+------+
|  1 |      1 | Aa       | A         |  8.5 |
|  2 |      2 | Bb       | B         |  8.6 |
|  3 |      3 | Cc       | C         |  8.7 |
|  4 |      4 | Dd       | D         |  8.4 |
+----+--------+----------+-----------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

Re your comment:

The `s1` and `s2` in this query are common called "table aliases" but you should think of them more like *row* aliases. They reference one row at a time, so you can compare the values in the respective rows.

Suppose there are two rows like this:

```
+----+--------+----------+-----------+------+
| id | Rollno | LastName | FirstName | Gpa  |
+----+--------+----------+-----------+------+
|  1 |      1 | Aa       | A         |  8.5 |
|  5 |      1 | Aa       | A         |  8.5 |
```

Which row can be indicated by `s1` and which row can be `s2` such that the join condition is true?

The two rows have the same Rollno, so the join condition `s1.rollno=s2.rollno` is satisfied either way.

One row has an `id` with a lesser value than the other, so for the join condition `s1.id > s2.id` to be satisfied, we know that `s2` is the first row with id 1, and `s1` is the second row with id 5.

Thus the two terms of the join condition together guarantee that `s1` and `s2` will reference two rows with the same Rollno, and `s2` will have a lesser `id` value.

```
+----+--------+----------+-----------+------+
| id | Rollno | LastName | FirstName | Gpa  |
+----+--------+----------+-----------+------+
|  1 |      1 | Aa       | A         |  8.5 | <-- s2
|  5 |      1 | Aa       | A         |  8.5 | <-- s1
```

We want to keep the "first" row with the lesser id value (`s2`), and delete the other one (`s1`).  Hence the `delete s1 from ...`. In MySQL's multi-table delete syntax, you specify which row will be deleted before the `from` keyword. The other row alias defined in the `from` clause (`s2`) will not be deleted.

Comment: Could I know more exactly on how `s1.id > s2.id` works.